# Why does this script start with a blank image?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script to scroll through images in an iframe. I can't figure out how to get the script to start on image 1 rather than start blank and then go to image 1.

Here is the script:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var limit = 8;
    var i = limit - 1;

function image_onclick(direction)
{
    i = ( i + ( (direction == 'prev')?limit-1:1 ) ) % limit;

    document.getElementById('image_box').innerHTML = '<img src=images/gallery/image' + (i+1) + '.jpg>';
}
</script>
```

---

This is the script in the body,

---

```
<div id="leaf1"><button onClick="image_onclick('prev');"><img src="images/leaf.gif" alt="leaf arrow" border="0"/></button></div>
<div id="image_box"></div>
<div id="leaf2"><button onClick="image_onclick('next');"><img src="images/leaf2.gif" alt="leaf arrow" border="0"/></button></div>
```

---

Comment: Looks like you've got some correct solutions here. Perhaps you could pick one? Otherwise, it's going to forever live in the "Unanswered" category.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.load or document.ready method and add following code to it.

```
 document.getElementById('image_box').innerHTML = '<img src=images/gallery/image1'.jpg>';
```

Or simply on page

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 document.getElementById('image_box').innerHTML = '<img src=images/gallery/image1'.jpg>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not put

```
document.getElementById('image_box').innerHTML = '<img src=images/gallery/image' + (1) + '.jpg>';
```

in a document.ready call?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing the inner quotes?

```
  = '<img src=images/gallery/image' + (i+1) + '.jpg>';
```

vs

```
  = "<img src='images/gallery/image" + (i+1) + ".jpg' >";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `image_onclick('next')` on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 0):

add `onload="image_onclick('next')"` to your body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a reason to load the initial image dynamically, why not just put the initial image inside the `<div>`.  Using scripting for such a simple task seems overhead.